# Ignore space in string stored in argument perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to execute a `.VB` script along with some other arguments.

I'm calling `system("$cmd")`, where

```
my $cmd = "Report.exe $app_env $rpt_Dir $eff_date";
```

and

```
my $rpt_Dir = "\\\\server\\folder\\Target Report\\test";
```

The problem I am having is that (I think) the space between `"Target Report"` is making the script treating it as 2 arguments.

And the reason why I didn't just surround the path with "" and pass it as an argument instead of saving it to a variable is that the path changes based on the date.

And it's not a first choice that I change the code in the `.VB` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the `system` call uses `cmd.exe` to process commands, so you need double quotes around any parameters that contain spaces

Set your `$cmd` up like this

```
my $cmd = qq{Report.exe $app_env "$rpt_Dir" $eff_date};
```

The `qq{...}` construction is identical to ordinary double quotes, but it allows you to choose your own delimiters so that you don't have to escape any embedded double quotes

Then you can write

```
system($cmd);
```

It is wrong to put quotes around a solitary scalar variable

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of args to [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). If you do this, you won't be tripped over by quote interpolation.

```
system  ( "Report.exe", $app_env, $rpt_Dir, $eff_date );
```

Comment: Not quite sure I'm understanding it correctly, but [`perldoc -f system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) says: "On Windows, only the `system PROGRAM LIST` syntax will reliably avoid using the shell; `system LIST`, even with more than one element, will fall back to the shell if the first spawn fails."

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enclose the `$rpt_Dir` variable in single quotes:

```
my $cmd = "Report.exe $app_env '$rpt_Dir' $eff_date";
```

and it will be treated as a single arguement